# Adding neutral lug to older load center

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

In the process of installing a remote subpanel from my older backfed load center.  The neutral/ground bar is attached to the service entrance via the screw midway, and the ground is at the base of the bar.  This is an atypical bar in comparison to the newer panels I have worked with. Each terminal is part of a single sliding rail.

What would be the best way to attach a neutral lug capable of handling #3AWG for a 100a subpanel?

Also I understand that per code I should rearrange the neutrals so each occupies a single terminal.

[image]

[image: Possible solution]

What problems could I run into by simply doing the above?  The lug is rated for 100a and would provide a direct path to the service neutral.

[image]

With a little bit of effort, I was able to get the #3 copper into one of the lower lugs. Any reason this might fail inspection?

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on this meter-main?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the only labeling on the box is the UL tag.  Box labeling appears to have fallen off.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using copper for this?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Copper is what was available locally

Comment: That is strange that aluminum is unavailable locally -- are you sure you don't live in/near a jurisdiction that bans aluminum wire?

Comment: Can you provide a closeup of that bottom set of fat lugs on your neutral bar?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel lower lug photos added, too small to handle #3

Comment: Can you figure out what size wire those lower four lugs will take, and what size the wire-binding screws there are as well?

Comment: Was able to get the #3 into one of the larger lugs, would you say that is better than attaching to the center screw as pictured?

Comment: Did all of the strands of the #3 copper go into the larger bottom lug?

Comment: I was able to get all of the strands of the #3 neutral into the lug.  I did, however, split the ground into two adjacent terminals.

Comment: what size is the ground wire? O.o